# ODE of second degree

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics

A frigate originally located in the plane moves at constant speed a in the positive direction along the vertical axis. At the same time, a galleon at the point of coordinates $(c, 0)$ sets off in pursuit (for a collision) at constant speed b. Show, using the fact that the galleon is always moving in the direction of the frigate, that the position $(x, y)$ of the galleon satisfies the equation.

$$x \dfrac {d^2 y}{dx^2} = \dfrac ab \sqrt {1+\left(\dfrac {dy}{dx}\right)^2}$$

Solve this equation, considering cases $a > b$ and $a < b$ separately

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tjEA.png) This is a picture of a part of homework I have been stuck for a full day and I don't now how to proceed.

Note:

$\dfrac {d^2 y}{dx^2}$ = second derivative of $y$; $\dfrac {dy}{dx}$ =  first derivative of y

Comment: You can find this problem in many elementary differential equations books.  An airplane flying in a cross-wind. A boat crossing a river with a current.  I first saw the version where a farmer is chasing a pig.

Comment: @GEdgar  does the De have  a solution with elementary functions ?

Comment: My teacher only proposed one textbook and I read through it but it doesn't even give me the right examples

Comment: As I recall, the solution is given implicitly.

Comment: Could you do a demonstration ?

Comment: If I may ask, where are you located ? I am in Pau.

Comment: @Christian Abinassif: Did you attempt to derive the differential equation? How so the present galleon position (c,0)  does not enter into the differential equation? –

Answer (score 1):

The equation being $$x y'' = \dfrac ab \sqrt {1+\left(y'\right)^2}$$ reduce the order $p=y'$ to get
$$x p'=\dfrac ab \sqrt {1+p^2}$$ which is separable. So
$$p=\sinh \left(\frac{a \log (x)}{b}+ c_1\right)=\sinh(c_1) \cosh \left(\frac{a \log (x)}{b}\right)+\cosh (c_1) \sinh \left(\frac{a
   \log (x)}{b}\right)$$ So, now, you need to compute
$$I=\int \cosh \left(\frac{a \log (x)}{b}\right)\,dx\qquad \text{and}\qquad J=\int \sinh \left(\frac{a \log (x)}{b}\right)\,dx$$ Let 
$$\frac{a \log (x)}{b}=t \implies x=e^{\frac{b t}{a}}\implies dx=\frac{b }{a}e^{\frac{b t}{a}}\,dt$$
$$I=\frac{b }{a}\int e^{\frac{b t}{a}}\cosh(t)\,dt\qquad \text{and}\qquad J=\frac{b }{a}\int e^{\frac{b t}{a}}\sinh(t)\,dt$$
Compute $(I+J)$ and $(I-J)$ to face simple integrals using $\cosh(t)\pm\sinh(t)=e^{\pm t}$